# Get/emulate touch event in Cordova app

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I have a HTML5 app, wich I want to port to Ubuntu as a Cordova app with Ubuntu SDK. It use touch events on a canvas and works fine in any browser, but no with Cordova. I bind the events like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
```

But touchStart and touchEnd functions are never called. It still not work with `canvas.ontouchstart = touchStart` however `ontouchstart in canvas` returns true. Is there any way to get/emulate the event with the sdk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the listener in anonymous function like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {touchStart;}, false);
```